# App like Pocket but for listening in car, including audio, video, and text-to-speech

Tags: speech-synthesis, bluetooth, podcast, car, audio-player

I frequently encounter interesting things online that I don't have time to read/watch/listen to at that moment, but have plenty of time driving in the car to listen to things.

I can throw articles into [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/) and then have it use Text-to-Speech on them while driving later, and that works OK, but navigating through them from the car controls doesn't work well, the text to speech has annoying pauses whenever the text has italics, it doesn't deal well with voice navigation prompt interruptions, etc. and only supports text.  I'd like an app that:

- Can read text articles out loud

  - Including PDFs of academic papers
- Can play the audio tracks of YouTube or other videos
- Can play audio recordings such as podcasts (individual episodes) or interviews or audiobooks
- Saves them all offline to play without an internet connection
- Saves my place per-item (unlike a music player app) so I can switch to something else and then come back to where I was.
- Can be controlled from Bluetooth play/pause next/prev controls, and can scrub forward and backward if I miss something.